# Tell Mathematica that the output of a function is a List / Vector

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, assumptions, discontinuity

I have a function (Piecewise) that returns a list, e.g.:

```
F[x_] := Piecewise[{{{x^2, x}, x < 0}, {{x, x^2}, x > 0}}, {0, 0}];
```

I would like to add another list (e.g. {2,3}) to the **output** of that function, i.e., I would like to obtain:

[image]

If I simply do:

```
{2, 3} + F[x]
```

I obtain:

```
{2 + F[x], 3 + F[x]}
```

,i.e.:

[image]

which is not what I want. Naturally, I could include the list I want to add ({2,3}) in every branch of the definition of the Piecewise function, e.g.:

```
Piecewise[{{{2, 3} + {x^2, x}, x < 0}, {{2, 3} + {x, x^2}, x > 0}, {2,3}}]
```

But this is unsatisfactory, because my actual problem is much more convoluted that this MWE, with many different cases in the piecewise function, and I also want to use the result of the function as a vector in matrix multiplications and so on.

I have tried things like:

```
MapThread[Plus,{{2, 3}, F[x]}] 

Add[x_List, y_List] := x + y;
Add[{2, 3}, F[x]]

Assuming[VectorQ[F[_]], {2, 3} + F[x]]
```

without any success. Is there any simple way of doing this? Thanks a lot

Comment: From the help of Piecewise: "If any of the preceding Subscript[cond, i] do not literally yield False, the Piecewise function is returned in symbolic form. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to your failed trial, I'm afraid you've severely misunderstood the usage of `MapThread`, `_List` and `Assuming`. Please notice `Assuming` only changes the global variable `$Assumptions` so it only has effect on those functions with `Assumptions` option; `MapThread` and `_List` simply don't do **mathematical** transforms, they won't handle `Piecewise` in the *clever* way you're imagining. (In my view, [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160759/1871) that you've also participated explains the topic well. )

As to your problem, the simplest solution I can think out is, transforming `Piecewise` to combination of `UnitStep` so the `F[x]` will be an explicit list. This can be easily done with `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep ``:

```
F[x_] = 
 Piecewise[{{{x^2, x}, x < 0}, {{x, x^2}, x > 0}}, {0, 0}] // Simplify`PWToUnitStep
(* {x (1 - UnitStep[-x]) + x^2 (1 - UnitStep[x]), 
 x^2 (1 - UnitStep[-x]) + x (1 - UnitStep[x])} *)

trial = F[x] + {2, 3};

Plot[trial, {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my problem and for explaining the answer so well. I really appreciate it! Simplify`PWToUnitStep is not documented, right?

Comment: @Luis Yeah, it's an undocumented function that looks strange at first glance but actually quite useful when dealing with various issues related to `Piecewise`. Just search in this site and you'll find more interesting examples :) .